# Using spring JPA specification to search join table

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_group")
@Data
public class Group{

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "group_hotel_catalogue",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "group_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "hotel_id")})
    @JsonSerialize(contentUsing = GroupHotelSerializer.class)
    private Set<Hotel> hotelCatalogue = new HashSet<>();
}

@Transactional
public interface HotelDao extends JpaRepository<Hotel, Integer>,
        JpaSpecificationExecutor<Hotel> {
    @Override
    List<Hotel> findAll(Specification spec);
}
```

I'd like to know if it is possible to reuse the JPA specification to search on a given set of data instead of on the whole database table from the repository. For example, I have a list of hotels which exists in the database, I only want to do a specification search on this subset of hotels. What should I do?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you read the documentation? Like this tutorial? https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/

Comment: I read it, but I want the search only applies to a given set, not whole database.

Comment: Why don't you just add a simple method to your hotel repository `HotelDao` that does the filtering at database table level then? What's the point of reusing the JPA specification?

Comment: @jbx how to get all hotel in the join table?

Comment: well i have no idea what your code or schema looks like. You didn't even put the `Hotel` entity.